# How to prove $x_0\in S^1$ s.t., $f(x_0)=f(-x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f:S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous function , then there exists $x_0\in S^1$ s.t., $f(x_0)=f(-x_0)$

I tried to calculate by taking $x:=(\cos{t}, \sin{t})$, but $f$ is  not specific, I can't.

Comment: A little hint: take $g$ defined as $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$.

Comment: What theorems do you know of that conclude with a statement such as “then there exists $x_0$ such that $g(x_0) = c$”? Construct a $g$ and choose a $c$ so that $g(x_0) =  c$ implies $f(x_0) = f(-x_0)$.

Comment: What is $S^1$? Cuz if 0 is in $S^1$, F(0)=F(0)

Comment: $S^1:=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2|a^2+b^2=1\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need one point $x_0$ on circle such that  $f(x_0)=f(-x_0)$.

Let  g be an odd real-valued continuous function on a circle;Pick an arbitrary $x$.

if $g(x)$=0 then we are done otherwise $g(x)>0$ without loss of generality 
now since g is odd function $g(-x)<0$ so by Intermediate value theorem 
there is $y$ s.t $g(y)$=0 between x and -x and so $g(y)$=0.

Now only question is what odd function we can choose so take $g(x)$=$f(x)$ $-$ $ f(-x)$
this function is clearly odd and continuous since f is continuous.So this function work for us now if g(x) is even then it is trivially true that $f(x)$ $=$ $f(-x)$ hence we consider odd function $g(x)$.

Also there is generalization of this known as Borsuk–Ulam theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$ has no zeros.

Check how $g(x)$ relates to $g(-x)$.

Now assume there is no such $x_0$ as in the question.

Can you finish from here?